# Photo has color data, but shows as black and white

Tags: colors, images

Thanks for reading.  I have a black and white photograph, that I just thought was black and white.

However, I have noticed that it is color in the windows preview if I view that folder as thumbnails in Explorer.

I would love to have the colors show normally, but haven't figured out how to make them show.  I've tried opening it in Photoshop and twiddling the color settings, etc, but no luck.  I don't really know what I'm doing in that department.

Any ideas on how to make this into a color pic?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to know what camera it was taken with and what file format it's in.

Comment: No idea - just copied it off the Internet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a JPEG, chances are that the photo was originally in color, then was edited to black and white but the editing program didn't update the JPEG thumbnail (which is stored in the file itself).

Note that Windows Explorer itself caches thumbnails into its own database - `Thumbs.db` in XP, not sure about later versions.

Comment: Hmm.  That probably means the picture itself really is  BW then.  Oh well - thanks!